# custom taxonomy don't return a value

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have initiated couple of custom taxonomies, using the following code

```
function sources_init() {

register_taxonomy('sources','post',array(
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'labels' => array (
            'name'              => _x( 'News Sources', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'News Source', 'taxonomy singular name'),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Search News Sources' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Topic' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Topic:' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Sources' ),
            'update_item'       => __( 'Update Sources' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add a News source' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( 'New News Source' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'News Sources' ),

        ),
          $args = array( 
            'labels'                => $lables,
            'public'                => true,
            'query_var'             => true,
            'show_ui'               => true,
            'update_count_callback' => 'update_post_term_count',
            'show_admin_column'     => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 
                    'slug'          => 'sources'
                     )
            )       
));
}
add_action( 'init', 'sources_init', 0 );
```

this is an example of code I am using, and there is no problem for now, specially when I call a custom post type in its template **archive-slug-name.php**. But the problem appears in two places:

1- **wp_list_categories()**

```
<?php $taxonomy = 'sources'; 
              $title = '';
              $args = array(
                    'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                    'title_li'     => $title,
                    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
              );
        ?>
        <ul>
            <?php wp_list_categories('title_li=&include=45,51'); ?>
        </ul>
```

2- using **tax_query** tag to show cpt in its each category page:

```
$loop = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type' => 'documents',
'posts_per_page' => 20,
'tax_query' => array(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'sources',
    'terms' => get_queried_object_id(),
)),
));
```

So is there any problem with the way I initiated the custom Taxonomy? Or the problem with the way I call the categories?

**Edit** 
[image: screenshot for taxonomy slug and cat iD]

Comment: In both cases you are using term IDs. For starters does `wp_list_categories()` work in very general case, without IDs?

Comment: yes with no problem.

Comment: Then are you sure your IDs are correct and belong to valid terms?

Comment: yes, that would be a problem for the first case, but the second doesn't require a term ID. Am I right?

Comment: You are very clearly using one in second case too?.. `'terms' => get_queried_object_id()` Value might not be what you assume.

Comment: true.. does removing it suppose to pull posts from mentioned taxonomy? as I tried it but it show nothing.

Comment: No. Just dump the value of ID and double check that it's for valid term. Same in first case, are you sure 45 and 51 are valid term IDs?

Comment: I just added screenshot with taxonomy slug and ID